# Why component is showing null in test? I am using React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need some help with my test. I have a component called "DashBoard" in "App" component, that becomes visible if user is authenticated. DashBoard code is listed below

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import SignIn from "./components/SignIn";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp";
import DashBoard from "./components/DashBoard";

function App(props) {
    return (
        <div data-testid='app'>
            <Router>
                <Navigation/>
                <Route exact path='/' component={SignIn}/>
                <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp}/>
                {props.isAuthenticated ? <Route path='/dashboard' component={DashBoard}/> : <Redirect to='/' />}
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.authentication.isAuthenticated
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

**Need help here.** When i run test DashBoard component comes `null`. It should not come `null`. Test is listed below

```
import React from 'react';
import {fireEvent, wait, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react';
import renderWithRedux from "./helpers/renderWithRedux";
import App from '../src/App';
import {generateState} from "./helpers/generateState";

afterEach(cleanup);

describe.only('App', () => {
  let state;
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    state = {
      authentication:{
        isAuthenticated: false
      }
    }
  });

  function renderApp(props={}, state = generateState()){
    return renderWithRedux(<App />, state);
  }

  test('should display Dashboard if user is authenticated', async () => {
    const {queryByTestId} = renderApp();
    fireEvent.click(queryByTestId('sign-in-button'));
    state.authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
    await wait(() => expect(queryByTestId('dash-board')).not.toBeNull());

  });
});
```

Comment: DashBoard isn't supposed to be rendered because you're not at /dashboard route . And you may have hard time testing routes in Jest because it's not real browser. Check https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router for starters.

Comment: You could try to access the `pathname` with the `history` in a way similar to this `await waitFor(() => expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual('/dashboard'));` . Hope it helps!

Comment: @reymon359 
it does pass my test but in code coverage it is not touching 
`{props.isAuthenticated ? <Route path='/dashboard' component={DashBoard}/> : <Redirect to='/' />}`